# React - freeze piece of the state?

Tags: reactjs, state

I have pecuilar input field which on click opens dropdown with checkboxes options. When I type in this input, I need to show only the options that include typed characters. It works fine as I add characters, but as I empty an array of options (which is stored in state), I don't get values back.
I tried freezing piece of state (options), by using Object.freeze, and use this "frozen" array as starting point. But it doesn'r freeze, and I have no clue how to do this. Here's the code

```
let coppiedOptions = [...state.inputs.names.options];
coppiedInputs.forEach(el => Object.freeze(el));
let newOptions = coppiedOptions.filter(opt => opt.value.includes(action.value));
```

I am using use Reducer, so I get value as an action payload. And this "newOptions" is being passed into state in reducer

Comment: I hope I understood your problem correctly, you have some sort of search bar that filter option by showing only the option that includes the searched value, and when you empty the search field no options is showing?

Comment: Yes. Beacuse I am coppying from the state, and state always changes, so I always get changed data, but I need to somehow freeze initial data. When I hard code values in "coppiedOptions", it works. So I need somehow to get options from state once, and freeze them. The more I think about this, the more it seems impossible to be done this way.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution was writting another options array, with different name, with same data, to coppy it and use it for filtering, while changing only the first one. I quest it is impossible to do with only one set of options. I am an idiot

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).